# PHP for MSSQL insert runs but no data inserted

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a PHP script that is attempting to `INSERT` form data into a MSSQL database.  When I run the script, the script runs successfully, but the `INSERT` doesn't seem to post the data.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
//collect data from form
$username  = $_POST['username'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
$address   = $_POST['address'];
$city      = $_POST['city'];
$state     = $_POST['state'];
$zip       = $_POST['zip'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];

$serverName     = "192.168.1.1"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"mydatabase", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn           = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     $sql    = "INSERT INTO Member_Details (FirstName,LastName,Address,City,State,Zip_Code,Telephone,Email,User_Name,Password,Is_Validated) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     $params = array($firstname,$lastname,$address,$city,$state,$zip,$telephone,$email,username,$password,0);
     $stmt   = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
     echo "You were successfully registered for user name " . $username;
}else {
     echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

I have confirmed that form data is being passed successfully via the message passed upon the running of the script.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Mike

Comment: Not your current issue but your passwords should be hashed. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php for errors.

Comment: `username` in your `$params` array is missing its `$`. Is that just a typo in your question here, or is your actual code like that?

Comment: Also, you check `$conn` and "Something went wrong" if you can't connect, but after that your code assumes that the query will execute successfully. You should verify that it doesn't return false, and if it does, check for errors, something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-errors-examples

Comment: The error checking you recommended caught my error.  Turns out I had two column names incorrectly defined in the query.  All fixed now.  Thanks to all for their help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, you have to prepend the dbo. (or whatever the owner of the table is) to the table name.

like

```sql
insert into dbo.tablename (cols) values (vals)
```